# Breaking strings into different lines in ant build.xml files

Tags: xml, ant, build.xml

I'd like to know how to shorten lines containing long string literals in my ant build.xml file.  For example:

```
<target name="foo"
        description="I sure do have a lot to say.  Blah Blah.  This is getting awfully wide, etc."
        depends="A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,...,ZZ">
  ...
</target>
```

Obviously, I could shorten the depends attribute value by creating a tree of dependencies, but that wouldn't work in other cases, such as the description.  What's the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insert a newline:

```
<target name="foo"
        description="I sure do have a lot to say.  Blah Blah.  
                     This is getting awfully wide, etc."
        depends="A,B,C,D,E,F,
                 G,H,I,...,ZZ">
  ...
</target>
```

Comment: D'oh!

Follow up question: What if it is a long string without white space?

Comment: JB, my concern isn't how it's displayed in my editor but for a line length limit in our code base.

Thanks for all of your help.